# Loading bundles "on demand" in aurelia (using aurelia-cli)

Tags: bundle, aurelia

We are using the aurelia-cli for a single page application. It has the concept of multiple user modules (simple folders with view and view-models basically). Now as the application grows we want a way of not loading all modules up front. For example one user may only have access to 3 out of 20 modules.

Now the question is, how can we define bundles of modules and only load these on demand based on a condition at runtime?

We have managed to create bundles by editing the `aurelia.json` file. Our file looks like this for example

```
"bundles": [
{
    "name": "my-module-bundle.js",
    "source": [
      "[**/my-module/*.js]",
      "**/my-module/*.{css,html}"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "app-bundle.js",
    "source": [
      "[**/*.js]",
      "**/*.{css,html}"
    ]
  }, 
...
```

This causes all the code for "my-module" to end up in its own bundle.
This also works in a sense that if no code has a reference to the "my-module" the bundle will not be downloaded and executed.

However... if we want to load this module dynamically based on a certain condition we are out of luck since we would need to reference the module thus causing it to download.

Is there any way around this problem? Can we for example load a bundle on demand using code?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think this setup does what you think it does. I think that app-bundle will still include the code in the `my-module` folder. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you're right, you'd need to exclude my-module directory from app-bundle using "exclude". Johan, is it good enough to only load the module when the user routes to a page within that module? Doing this would naturally load the bundle when the route is requested, and just means you have to split modules into their own pages/routes

Comment: Check out my multiple bundle test repo https://github.com/MattGiesa/aurelia-multiple-bundle-example/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @mgiesa, how do you handle service registration?  I have multiple modules I want to bundle independently.  Right now the services are all registered in app.ts, but I need to not reference them there in order to split the modules into bundles.  Is there a concept of a bundle version of app.ts?

Comment: I don't manually register services, so I'm not sure, but I would try dividing the services based on where they're used. if some are used in only a specific module (which are divided by routes as I mentioned in my comment and therefore "guarded" by a single parent component) then register them in the top-most component within that module/route. does that make sense?

Comment: @mgiesa, it makes sense, but I don't necessarily have a top-most component.  There are several routes that could end up causing the module to load.  Ideally, each module is just a feature, and the feature has an index.js file with a configure method that would load the services.  I'm struggling to figure out how to demand-load a feature based on visiting a route.